# ES6 Formatting in Sublime Text 3 / VS Code

Tags: ecmascript-6, coding-style, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

I was watching a video tutorial and I found ES6 arrow function ( => ) was formatted in a symbol.

[image]

Please let me know is there any plugin/extension or some customization needed to be done to achieve es6 formatting.

Comment: That isn't ES6 formatting, it's a plugin to make `=>` display as an actual arrow, something I think you're worse off having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is font with [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) something like [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode).

[image]

Yes, it is available for vscode.

[Installing font](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki#installing-font)

[Setting up vscode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/VS-Code-Instructions)